# What is a better way to check for a nil object before calling a method on it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method call I have to use...

```
financial_document.assets.length
```

But `financial_document.assets` could be `nil`.

I could use...

```
financial_document.assets.nil? ? '0' : financial_document.assets.length
```

Is there a less repetitive way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I would use the **`or`** operator/keyword:

```
(financial_document.assets or []).length
```

Either way, `.length` is called on an array, giving you `0` if `nil`.

Answer (score 8):

Dave W. Smith is on the right track.

Check this out: http://www.nach-vorne.de/2007/4/24/attr_accessor-on-steroids

One easy solution would look something like this:

```
class FinancialDocument
  attr_accessor :assets
  def assets
    @assets ||= Array.new
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 7):

The less repetitive way of dealing with this is to ensure that financial_document.assets is always a non-null object, by arranging for it to hold an appropriate sentinel value (e.g., an empty collection, or a special object that has degenerate behavior).

See [The Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Answer (score 3):

Case 1:

`financial_document` and `assets` have has many relationship. In this case, `financial_document.assets` always returns an array. So `financial_document.assets.size` would give you `0` if no matching child entry is found, and size otherwise.

Case 2:

`assets` is just a method/attribute in `financial_document`.
Then have the `assets` method return array, so that you can always call .size on it. Just like Joel has pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

In such case I use [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) gem:

```
financial_document.assets.andand.length || 0
```

Answer (score 3):

A more generic way to solve this class of problems is to add a try method to Object:

```
  ##
  #   @user.name unless @user.nil?
  # vs
  #   @user.try(:name)
  #
  def try(method, *args, &block)
    return nil unless method
    return nil if is_a?(NilClass) and [:id, 'id'].include?(method)
    self.send(method, *args, &block) if respond_to?(method)
  end
```

I believe ruby 1.9 already has a try method on Object.

Then `financial_document.assets.try(:length).to_i` would achieve your desired result.
This is because `nil.to_i` returns 0

Comment: try was backported in Ruby 1.8 for Rails 2.3 - see http://railscasts.com/episodes/152-rails-2-3-extras

Answer (score 1):

financial_document.assets.try(:length) || 0

try is a method that will invoke the object's method if its non nil otherwise just return nil. And try on nil methods will always return nil instead of throwing an exception.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

This is the Ruby way to do this!

Comment: The Rails way, not the Ruby way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without additional gems. I have been using `||`, `andand`, `try`, but the following looks simpler. I think it is the ruby way to confirm to Dave's null object pattern.

```
financial_document.assets.to_a.length
```

Answer (score 0):

This being Ruby, you could add a length method to NilClass and have it always return 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a bit shorter:

```
financial_document.assets ? financial_document.assets.length : '0'
```

because

```
financial_document.assets == !financial_document.assets.nil?
```

but in general, IMHO there's no less repetitive way, only various workarounds. (And this is one of the things I don't like so much in Ruby.) You can make sure that objects aren't null (as other people are suggesting here) - but you can't do that everywhere. You can wrap up the nil-checking code in helper methods or in begin-rescue blocks.

For example, rather than adding length method to nil object (which is IMHO a dirty hack), I'd wrote a helper method - a "length getter":

```
def fd_length(financial_document)
  financial_document.assets ? financial_document.assets.length : '0'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in the model that returns 0 or the length. This keeps you from having to do a convaluted thing in your view. Things like this can normally be done in the model.

```
class FinancialDocument

  def assets_length
    assets.length.blank? 0 : assets.length
  end
end
```